# Auto update local repository upon schema change

Tags: git, version-control, datagrip, redgate, intellij-datagrip

With DataGrip, I know there's a way to generate SQL scripts based on the database schema (Right click on the table > `SQL Scripts` > `SQL Generator`). However, is there a way to get DataGrip to automatically update these generated SQL scripts whenever the schema changes via queries (DDL) or the UI (`Modify Table` option)?

Right now, if I want my SQL script files to be under version control and if I want these files to reflect the latest state/schema of my database, I have to:

1. Manually modify the file(s).
2. Copy the contents of the file (query) and paste it onto a console in DataGrip.
3. Run the query from the console in order to update the database schema.
4. If step 3 succeeds, commit the changes in my file to my local GIT repository. If step 3 fails, start over from step 1.

Instead, I want to:

1. Make a schema change directly on DataGrip via a query or `New > Create Table` option or `Right click on the table > Modify Table` option.
2. (If step 1 succeeds) Be shown a change set on DataGrip itself, and upon clicking something like `Save` / `Commit`, modify the corresponding SQL scripts in my local repository and create a new commit. This will then trigger my CI/CD pipeline to build, test and deploy my changed schema.

P.S: This is similar to what Red-Gate's [`SQL Source Control`](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) can do in SQL Server Management Studio. Unfortunately, they don't have a plugin for DataGrip.

Comment: Do you want this to happen only via datagrip? Instead, you can write a shell script to automate this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now DataGrip cannot automatically update SQL files according to schema changing. We have the idea to implement this in the future. I think the best ticket to upvote will be: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3852

Anyway, your current algorithm seems to be not the most effective. What I would offer:

1. Open *Files* pane (Ctrl/Cmd+1) and attach the folder with your DDL scripts there.
2. Associate these files with the needed data sources via **Preferences | Database | SQL Resolution Scopes**
3. Optionally, install VCS plugin to commit and push files just from DataGrip. Learn more here: https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/06/01/tutorial-how-to-use-git-with-datagrip/
4. When you modify your files just run these scripts against the data sources you need. The context menu can also be used for this: 
   [image]